# Replace file in all subdirectories batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a folder `C:\Config\` that contains many subfolders. Each of the subfolders contains a file `Logo.bmp`. I want to run a batch script to copy and replace a new `Logo.bmp` file into all of these subfolders.

I am trying this with no luck. What can I do to get this working?

```
FOR /R C:\Config\ %%G IN (Logo.b?p) do Echo xcopy /y G:\Logo.bmp "%%G"
```

Comment: Since `Logo.b?p` can also match files other than `Logo.bmp`, I'd insert `if /I "%%G"=="Logo.bmp"`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have an *echo* command placed before the *xcopy* command. If you remove the *Echo* part, it should work as intended.